# how to re deploy a node app on Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, github-actions

I deployed a node js app on AWS EC2 amazon linux 2 so now I'm trying to update my project how can I push new changes of node app to EC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I've found for EC2 is to SSH to the machine, then do a `git pull` from your repo, onto the machine.

Comment: how can I do git pull from my repo into the machine?

Comment: ssh onto the machine, clone your repo like you would normally; go into the project directory, and run git pull. Then if it's buildable, build it locally.